# I am trying to write test cases in node js with fullstack-react-2.0.0

Tags: node.js

I want to write test case in node js for  web application .please suggest me. I am trying to node js with fullstack-react-2.0.0 but when i type command on command prompt but it gives error.please suggest me.

Comment: 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\C-Vikash.Kumar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.12.1
3 info using node@v4.4.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart fullstack-react@2.0.0
6 info start fullstack-react@2.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info fullstack-react@2.0.0 Failed to exec start script
`

Comment: 9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\C-Vikash.Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\C-Vikash.Kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)

Comment: 9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid fullstack-react@2.0.0
11 verbose cwd E:\jswork\fullstack-react-2.0.0
12 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\C-Vikash.Kumar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v4.4.4
15 error npm  v2.12.1
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error fullstack-react@2.0.0 start: `npm install; npm run webpack; node server`
17 error Exit status 1

Comment: 18 error Failed at the fullstack-react@2.0.0 start script 'npm install; npm run webpack; node server'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the fullstack-react package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     npm install; npm run webpack; node server
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls fullstack-react
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]